# Is there any way to prevent a user from registering/using his own signal handler and always use a particlar handler?

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, signal-handling

My requirement is: 
                I have a signal handler in my tool, which is registered and used between some particular interval (i am using timer).

Now this signal handler should NOT allow any other handler to be registered after this handler is once registered. (But this restriction is only for a short duration, means after that duration the user is free to invoke his own handler)

Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
 sigset_t mask;
 struct sigaction sa;
 printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIG);
 sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
 sa.sa_sigaction = handler; // This handler should override all handlers
 sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL);
 sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
 sev.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;
```

Note: My tool is actually written in C++, but the concepts are so close and since more people are familiar with it, i am putting a C tag too, with C++
**Please feel free to ask for more clarifications (if you need)**

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This can be achieved, and in fact i have done that by writing a sigaction wrapper around the actual one, and using the `dlsym` and `RTLD_NEXT` technique.

Here is the code snippet of my wrapper:

```
enter code here
int sigaction(int sig, const struct sigaction *act, struct sigaction *oact)
{

 struct sigaction sa;
 printf("My sigaction called\n");

 if((Timerflag==1)&&(sig==SIGUSR1))
 {
   sa.sa_sigaction=my_handler;
   sa.sa_flags=0;

   return LT_SIGACTION(sig,&sa,NULL);
  }
  else if(Timerflag==0)
    return LT_SIGACTION(sig, act, oact);  
}
```

Finally, i think everyone knows, how to get the libc handle using dlsym :-)
Unfortunately, nobody could give me this idea in "stackoverflow".

Comment: That won't work against code which performs the syscall directly, rather than through libc.

Comment: @Dietrich: For me it will work well, because app would connect via libc. Also i guess, nowhere in my question i have mentioned that app will perform syscall directly.

Comment: @Dietrich: Also i wonder what do you mean by "direct syscall" :) syscalls are always made via the syscall wrapper, which always connects via the libc.

Comment: On x86, there is a syscall opcode.  Libc is just a library.  Other systems are similar.

Comment: @Dietrich: There is no way, that you can directly use that opcode :) That opcode is mapped to a header file, and every syscall has a unique code...i am more aware of that, because we work on system libraries..so it's just not the API :)

Comment: `__asm__( "xor %%ebx,%%ebx ; lea 1(%%ebx),%%eax ; int $128" );`

Comment: I will gladly sacrifice a reputation point to downvote such a brazen display of ignorance. Listen to what the experts are saying, kingsmasher.

Comment: OK better example: `__asm__( "call 1f ; jmp myhandler\n1:\tpop %%ecx ; mov $14,%%ebx ; mov $48,%%eax ; int $128" );` (call/pop trick makes it work even with pic).

Comment: @LaC: The experts are the "kings" and he's obviously here to "smash" our authority. ;-)

Comment: @R..: Appreciate your sense of humour and also your knowledge :)

Comment: @LaC: Well, what is the fault in overwriding a sigaction action? What makes you downvote my answer?

Comment: You say you're writing a test harness, so I'll say first that test harnesses sometimes do need to pull dirty tricks like this one. However, in addition to the assembly-language tricks shown by R.., dlsym interception will not work against internal calls to sigaction from libc itself (yes, it does do them sometimes) or from libraries after yours in the link order, nor will it work against calls to the *other* signal-establishing functions (even though libc forwards them all to sigaction). Thus, maybe this is your best option at this time, but you should expect it to break someday.

Comment: @Zack: Hope it does not break, till the time i am in the company for whom i have written the code. :-) (Sorry, just kidding..yes, absolutely true, and your point is valid. I tried this as i was designing a timer functionality on LeakTracer, and the other method - SIGEV_THREAD, did not support in our distro. So, at last we resorted to using timerfd mechanism. Fortunately we haven't used the above trick. But just tried it once and it seemed to work.)

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are writing a library.  The answer is no, No, NO, **NO**!  Just write in the documentation that client code should not register a handler for that signal.  If you can't trust the users of your library not to break things, then you should be writing apps, not libraries.

No matter what you do to make your handler be prioritized over the others, it will not work if the other code does the same thing.  Here's a very relevant blog post about Windows developers who want to make a "topmost window" (kind of like a "top priority" signal handler).

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

P.S. In Linux, there is no good way to give different levels of authority at a finer level than the process level.

**P.P.S.** To clarify, if my code is running in your process, then there is nothing you can do.  You already lost.  My code can access your private member variables, free your memory, close your files, and unload your libraries.  (You can write kernel code or run everything in virtualization, but that would be terrible.)

Comment: @Dietrich: Your guess is correct, i am developing a test tool. The user's test code is linked to my tool. Once my timer starts, the user should not be allowed to invoke his handler or register, however he is free to send the particular signal. Once the timer expires, the user is free to invoke or register his handler. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: THere is no way to do that. Unless, of course, you want to write a kernel driver.

Comment: Sorry, that is out of my scope of my development :(

Comment: @kingsmasher1 For clarity, no it is not possible.  It sounds like this might be a case of the "XY Problem".  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by preventing some random code from registering a signal handler?

Comment: It depends on what level of "not allowed" you mean. You could do ugly hacks wrapping the libc functions (`sigaction`, etc.) to make them fail when called early, but a malicious program could get around this by writing the syscall code directly in asm. To run sandboxed malicious code you really need either a separate user/address space and a supervisor process tracing it, or (better) a complete virtual machine.

Comment: @R: I think you are referring to the dlsym technique :)

Comment: @Dietrich: The answer is YES YES YES YES..see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If handling signal is a problem, then get rid of signal ! You can use select as a way to sleep with wahtever precision your os granularity allows. calling selects with null stes (no descriptor in any sets) and a valid timeout is basically a blocking system call with a timed lower boundary.

If you don't want to block, then you can put the timer in it's own thread, and use semaphore or mutex or whatever for synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is not to use signals for timers. You could instead simply create a POSIX timer with `SIGEV_THREAD` delivery (handler runs in a new thread rather than a signal handler) or create your own thread and `nanosleep` in it for the desired interval. This has the advantage that the timer expiration handler is not restricted only to async-signal-safe functions and you don't have to worry about conflicting signal handlers being installed.

Comment: SIGEV_THREAD is not supported in our distribution. Later i reverted to timerfd.